# Generate a video with transparent background AND fade in fade out effect

Tags: ffmpeg

I’m using this (python) command to generate a video with just a string and a transparent background:

```
cmd = [
    "ffmpeg", "-y",
    "-loglevel", "panic",
    "-f", "lavfi",
    "-i", f"color=green@0.0:s=1920x1080:rate=25:duration={duration},format=rgba", 
    "-vf", f"drawtext=text='{string}':fontfile='{font}':fontsize={font_size}:fontcolor={font_color}:x=(w-tw)-{bottom_right_offset.split(':')[0]}:y=(h-th)-{bottom_right_offset.split(':')[1]}:borderw=2:bordercolor=black", 
    "-vcodec", "prores_ks",
    "-profile:v", "4",
    "-pix_fmt", "yuva444p10le",
    output_file
]
subprocess.run(cmd)
```

It works great, but I would also like to add a fade in / fade out effect to my text (so that, when I will add this video on top of another inside Adobe Premiere, the text will slowly appear and disappear). I haven’t been able to find out how to do that. I can either get a transparent background or get the fade in / fade out effect but it seems like I can’t get the two working together. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve both a transparent background and a fade-in/fade-out effect for your text in the video using FFmpeg, you can modify your command to include the fade filter for the text. However, since you're working with a transparent background and want to apply fade effects, it's a bit tricky because you want the fade effect to apply to the text's alpha channel rather than the entire frame.

One approach is to create your text with an alpha channel and then apply fade in and fade out effects to this alpha channel. Unfortunately, drawtext doesn't directly support fading text in and out. Instead, you can use a workaround by generating a separate video (or overlay) with your text on a transparent background and then applying fade effects to this overlay before combining it with your transparent background video.

Here's how you can modify your existing command to include a fade-in and fade-out effect on the text. This solution involves using the enable='between(t,{start_time},{end_time})' option within the drawtext filter to control the opacity of the text over time, essentially simulating a fade effect. Note that {start_time} and {end_time} should be replaced with the times (in seconds) you want the fade in to start and the fade out to end, respectively.

```
   cmd = [
    "ffmpeg", "-y",
    "-loglevel", "panic",
    "-f", "lavfi",
    "-i", f"color=green@0.0:s=1920x1080:rate=25:duration={duration},format=rgba", 
    "-vf", f"drawtext=text='{string}':fontfile='{font}':fontsize={font_size}:fontcolor={font_color}@1: x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h-th)/2:enable='between(t,{start_time},{fade_in_duration})+between(t,{duration}-{fade_out_duration},{duration})',format=rgba,fade=t=in:st={start_time}:d={fade_in_duration}:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st={duration}-{fade_out_duration}:d={fade_out_duration}:alpha=1", 
    "-vcodec", "prores_ks",
    "-profile:v", "4",
    "-pix_fmt", "yuva444p10le",
    output_file
]
subprocess.run(cmd)
```

In this modified command, replace {start_time}, {fade_in_duration}, and {fade_out_duration} with your desired times in seconds for the fade-in to start, the duration of the fade-in, and the duration of the fade-out, respectively. The @1 in fontcolor={font_color}@1 makes sure the text is fully opaque when it's supposed to be visible, and the fade filters adjust the opacity over time. This command assumes the fade in starts at {start_time} seconds into the video, lasts for {fade_in_duration} seconds, and then a fade out starts {fade_out_duration} seconds before the end of the video and lasts until the end.

Remember, this approach directly manipulates the opacity of the text overlay. Adjust {start_time}, {fade_in_duration}, and {fade_out_duration} according to your video's requirements for the fade effects.

Comment: also I recommend to you check https://github.com/viddotech/videoalchemy

Comment: *Unfortunately, drawtext doesn't directly support fading text in and out* --> it does. See the 3rd to last example at https://ffmpeg.org//ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1 You can also apply it directly to the alpha option instead of fontcolor_expr

Comment: @MohammadHosseinGerami thanks! The command you gave me produces empty video files though. Videoalchemy looks great I’ve already used it today!

Comment: I also tried adapting the code @Gyan mentioned to my case but it’s not drawing any text. But it’s a complicated command so I might have messed up somewhere

 ```"-vf", f"drawtext=text='{string}':fontfile='{font}':fontsize={font_size}:fontcolor_expr={font_color}%{{eif\\\\: clip(255*(1*between(t\\, {DS} + {FID}\\, {DE} - {FOD}) + ((t - {DS})/{FID})*between(t\\, {DS}\\, {DS} + {FID}) + (-(t - {DE})/{FOD})*between(t\\, {DE} - {FOD}\\, {DE}) )\\, 0\\, 255) \\\\: x\\\\: 2 }}:x=(w-tw)-{bottom_right_offset.split(':')[0]}:y=(h-th)-{bottom_right_offset.split(':')[1]}:borderw=4:bordercolor=black"```